# Could not find MyFirstAndro.apk

Tags: android

i'm new in android developpment. i create my forst app but when running it, i'm facing this error **Could not find MyFirstAndro.apk!**. Could someone help me please?
regards

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Right click on your project, then click on Properties

On the shown window, choose Android from left side list

Uncheck the "Is Library" option, which is at the bottom right side of the window.